# Extract top part of bitmap in android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, crop

Is there a simple way to extract top part of bitmap like on the attached image and get only bottom part of bitmap? [image]

Answer (score 2):

It is quite easy actually. You have to use the method;

```
Bitmap dest=Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height);
```

Here x and y are coordinates of starting points. In your case you want to set x to 0, y to something, width to the real width and height to a shorter one. Beware that the width and height you enter cannot be larger than the original bitmap's dimensions.

Comment: I did a search for how to get a portion of a bitmap and this answer came up! =]